# Is there a way to fade in/out a view (e.g. an Image) when changing the content of said view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an `Image`, `predictionManager.prediction.sentiment.currentSentiment.0`, where `predictionManager` is an `@EnvironmentObject` and `predictionManager.prediction` is an `@Published` variable. `predictionManager.prediction.sentiment.currentSentiment.0` gets changed to a new `Image`, at which point I would like the original `Image` to fade out and the new one to fade in.

I attempted to do this by using the `.onReceive(publisher:) {}` modifier like so:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    [...]

    @EnvironmentObject private var predictionManager: PredictionManager
    @State private var imageOpacity: Double = 1

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                predictionManager.prediction.sentiment.currentSentiment.0
                    .font(.system(size: 100))
                    .opacity(imageOpacity)
                    .padding()
                    .onReceive(predictionManager.objectWillChange) {
                        imageOpacity = 0
                    }

                [...]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this code will always set the original `Image`'s opacity to `0` — it never gets set back to `1`. Since there isn't (to my knowledge) an `afterUpdate()` method which is called after the State is updated and the Image is switched out (or something to that effect), so how would achieve my goal?

If it helps, I imagine in UIKit I imagine that I'd do something like the following (I'm not going to test the code, so at the very least it will serve as pseudocode to aid the description of the problem):

```swift
var imageView = UIImageView() {
    willSet {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.imageView.alpha = 0
        }
    }
    didSet {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.imageView.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicit animation can be used in this scenario.  Hope the below example might help you in that direction

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var opacity = 0.2

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {

            withAnimation (.linear(duration: 2)) {
                self.opacity += 0.2
            }

        })  {
            Text("Animate Opacity")
            .padding()
            .opacity(opacity)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks — how would this be applied in my scenario? I understand that I could put the `withAnimation {} ` closure inside the `onReceive(publisher:) {}` modifier, though that would only run once when the image is changed. It wouldn't fade the image back in.